# How to close programmatically a layout made programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin, scrollview, programmatically-created

I created a ScrollView programmatically

```
private fun showSpinner() {
    /* SCROllL VIEW */
    var linearLayout: LinearLayout? = null
    linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linear1)
    val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this)
    
    // Create the view...
    val view: View = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.scroll_bckgrnd, linearLayout, false)
    ...
    ...
}
```

How do I close it programmatically ?

I didn't found something on the Internet

Every idea welcome and appreciate.

Comment: What do you mean closing it? Do you mean hiding it?

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  Your best bet may be to provide an image of what you want and what you have now.

Answer (score 0):

set the visibility to GONE, if that is what you need

Comment: You can add such stuff in the comments rather than creating a new answer for this

Comment: Thankyou Dato.Beriashvili. I did as you proposed " linearLayout!!.visibility = View.GONE" it's perfect.